# Querying association with Mongo_mapper with embedded document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I have a Users model with embedded Friend model. When a user registers, it saves their info, and then inserts they friend data.

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :first_name, String
  key :last_name, String
  key :email, String
  key :fb_user_id, String
  key :token, String
  timestamps!

class Friend
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  key :name, String
  key :fb_user_id, String
```

I've got the data in, but I'm having trouble querying the friend data that's inside the User object.

```
User.where("friends.id" => "4e03e796516d9b0f9c0001ab")
```

I can't use what's given back to get anything??

```
=> #<Plucky::Query friends.id: "4e03e796516d9b0f9c0001ab", transformer: #<Proc:0x00000102b0a830@/Users/^^^^^^^/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mongo_mapper-0.9.1/lib/mongo_mapper/plugins/querying.rb:79 (lambda)>>
```

What do I need to do to properly query the "name" and "fb_user_id" fields?

Comment: Try `User.where("friends._id" => "4e03e796516d9b0f9c0001ab")`.

Comment: In the database the key is "_id" and the above is an edge case that plucky/MM probably miss.  If that doesn't help, try `User.where("friends._id" => BSON::ObjectId.from_string("4e03e796516d9b0f9c0001ab"))`

Comment: Thanks Plastic Chicken--that BSON call was exactly what I needed.